# Why is a Run Statement faster than Run Script in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

We've got a simple query on a table with 7000 records. The query hits around 1,400 records.

When I press Run Statement it takes < 1Sec to execute.

When I press Run Script (F5) it takes 22 seconds. Is this normal or is this a network problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Run the data grid only fetches the first 50 rows (by default). As you page down it does further batch fetches, which take additional time. It will repeat that 29 times to get all 1400 rows, but on demand.

When you Run Script all of the rows (up to whatever limit you have set; I think the default is still 5000) are fetched in one go - so it is spending more time getting the data across the network straight away.

If you end up looking at all of the rows in the data grid then the amount of time spent transferring the data from the DB server to your PC is the same, it's just split into chunks; and there may be more overhead overall from the extra trips (depending on how many rows are fetched over JDBC in each batch anyway). If you page down right to the bottom of the grid, watch the 'fetched rows' display at the top of the grid; and when it gets to the end compare are 'All rows fetched in ...' time with the script run.

Comment: OK, this would explain the difference between the two buttons. Thank you. But now, they run this query using a web service. I assume then it takes 1 sec to get the data, but can it take 20-30 sec to transfer 1400 records with 3 fields or so to the requesting system?

Comment: The performance of the query itself or the network is nothing to do with whether you us Run or Run Script. Fetching 1400 rows in 22 seconds, and presumably 50 rows in about 0.75 seconds with Run (being more specific than <1sec might help), might indicate a network issue affecting both - or it might be something to do with your query, or a function it calls, etc. That's a separate question though, and Run appearing to be faster than Run Script (because it fetches less data) is normal.

Comment: It depends on the query and whether it can start to return results before it's finished. I'm not sure what the web service has to do with SQL Developer. I think all you've shown is that running in SQL Developer takes the same time (~20s) to get all 1400 rows as your web service does; which presumably eliminates some possible issues. If it takes the same time when run on the DB server, through SQL\*Plus, that would take the network out of the equation really, and mean you need to investigate the actual query?

Comment: Here comes my query select field1, field2 from mytable where field 3 is null or field3 = 1 or field3 = 3 and field2 is not null. When I do select count(*) from mutable it takes 0.05 or less and the count is 7000 records. when I do select count(*) from mytable where field 3 is null or field3 = 1 or field3 = 3 and field2 is not null it takes 23 seconds. What takes so long?

Comment: That is a separate question to what you asked here, but if you ask a new one, you'll need to provide more detail - like the table structure, the execution plan, whether any of those are virtual columns (which is the only think I can immediately think might have that kind of effect), etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657790/why-does-is-null-slows-this-query-down

Comment: you're too fast @AlexPoole - but your answer is spot on, per usual :)