# Why does checking for null slow this query down?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g

I got this table containing 7,000 records

desc ARADMIN.V_PKGXMLCODE

```
Name                  Null     Type          
--------------------- -------- ------------- 
REQUEST_ID            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15)  
AVAILABILITY                   VARCHAR2(69)  
XML_CODE                       CLOB          
PACKAGENAME_UNIQUE             VARCHAR2(50)  
CATALOG                        NUMBER(15)    
CHILD                          VARCHAR2(255) 
CLASSIFICATION_SYSTEM          NUMBER(15)    
E_MAIL                         VARCHAR2(69)
```

The query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ARADMIN.V_PKGXMLCODE WHERE (CATALOG <> 0 AND CATALOG <> 2) AND (NOT (CHILD IS NULL));
```

takes less than one second.

The query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ARADMIN.V_PKGXMLCODE WHERE (CATALOG IS NULL OR (CATALOG <> 0 AND CATALOG <> 2)) AND (NOT (CHILD IS NULL));
```

takes 23 seconds.

Explain plan however claims it should go real quick...

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Does the first query do a full table scan too, or is there an index on field4 that it can use? And if there is, has the table been repeatedly deleted (not truncated) and repopulated with direct path inserts (i.e. with the `/*+ append */` hint)?

Comment: What about plan for 1st query?

Comment: `IS NULL` condition will ignore the index since you cannot index NULL values. Well you could certainly trick the optimizer by uaing a constant value along with NULLABLE column while indexing. But, to answer within the scope of your question, your second query will go for a **FULL TABLE SCAN** unless you trick the optimizer as I said earlier. Your 1st query could make use of the indexes and avoid FTS. 1. Please post explain plan for 1st query too. 2. Are the statistics up to date?

Comment: Also, are the cardinality estimates and the actual rows returned the same?

Comment: how can I find out which indexes are there? As far as I know we've got an index on field4 and field5.

Comment: the slow version returns 1494 records.

Comment: In a comment and an answer I offered (now deleted, because they were both wrong), I suggested two possibilities: displaying the results taking a long time - Alex Poole pointed out correctly that this can't be the issue since the OP selects COUNT(*), not the full set of rows. And I suggested the problem may be the network - but again, Alex pointed out correctly that this would slow down both queries, not just one. Wanted this here for the record, as I deleted my comment and answer.

Comment: If this is a VIEW and not a TABLE then it is next to impossible to answer your question. It all depends on what the view does. If it was a TABLE I'd say there is no way Oracle needs 27 seconds for a full-table-scan of 7,000 rows  and do some boolean operations, unless you run it on a Raspberry Pi maybe. Even one second seems a lot. The only reason I could come up with is high-watermark problems as pointed out by Alex below.

Comment: Again, I ran the query on the underlying table. The results are the same. The view is a dummy. Does nothing but hiding a few fields of the underlying.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think to get that kind of difference in execution speed would be to (a) have an index on `field4`, and (b) have a **lot** of empty data blocks; possibly from a high water mark set very high by repeated direct-path loads.

The first query would still use the index and perform as expected. But as null values are not indexed, the index cannot be used to check the `or field4 is null` condition, so it would fall back to a full table scan.

That in itself shouldn't be a problem here, as a full table scan of 7000 rows shouldn't take long. But since it *is* taking so long, something else is going on. A full table scan has to examine every data block allocated to the table to see if they contain any rows, and the time it's taking suggests there are a lot more blocks than you need to hold 7000 rows, even with inline CLOB storage.

The simplest way to get a lot of empty data blocks is to have a lot of data and then delete most of it. But I believe you said in a now-deleted comment on an earlier question that performance used to be OK and has got worse. That can happen if you do [direct-path inserts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN01509), particularly if you 'refresh' data by deleting it and then inserting new data in direct-path mode. You could be doing that with inserts that have the `/*+ append */` hint; or in parallel; or through SQL*Loader. Each time you did that the high water mark would move, as old empty blocks wouldn't be reused; and each time performance of the query that checks for nulls would degrade a little. After a lot of iterations that would really start to add up.

You can check the data dictionary to see how much space is allocated to your table (`user_segments` etc.), and compare that to the size of the data you think you actually have. You can reset the HWM by rebuilding the table, e.g by doing:

```
alter table mytable move;
```

(preferably in a maintenance window!)

As a demo I ran a cycle to direct-path insert and delete 7000 rows over a hundred times, and then ran both your queries. The first one took 0.06 seconds (much of which is SQL Devleoper overhead); the second took 1.260. (I also ran Gordon's, which got a similar time, as it still has to do a FTS). With more iterations the difference would become even more marked, but I ran out of space... I then did an `alter table move` and re-ran your second query, which then took 0.05 seconds.

Comment: So you suggesting I do alter table ARADMIN.V_PCKXMLCODE move; ?

Comment: Or rebuild it some other way - but you probably shouldn't do that while people might be accessing it. I'm trying to think of a query that will show that is definitely the issue first, and i haven't come up with better than looking at `user_segments` - a real DBA might chip in an idea. You also need to identify if direct-path loads are actually happening; if so the problem will just gradually come back. How is the data in the table maintained? And from its name... is it actually a view? Well, yes, the plan says the actual table is T111 - so how is *that* maintained?

Comment: I went ahead and ran the query on the table the view is accessing. Exactly the same results. Trying to find out how the data is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting.  I would expect the query to have the same performance, because Oracle has a good optimizer and shouldn't be confused by the `NULL`.

How does this version have better performance?

```
select x1.cnt + x2.cnt + x3.cnt
from (select count(*) as cnt
      from MYTABLE
      where field4 = 1 and child is not null
     ) x1 cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from MYTABLE
      where field4 = 4 and child is not null
     ) x2 cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from MYTABLE
      where field4 is null and child is not null
     ) x3;
```

This version should be able to take advantage of an index on `MYTABLE(field4, child)`.

Comment: what's x1 x2 x3? It says ORA-00904: "X3": invalid identifier?

Comment: @Thomas - they are the table aliases for the inline views; they should be `x3.cnt` etc.

Comment: @Thomas . . . That is with the proposed index?

Comment: Very sorry Gordon. I messed up the original query. It actually looks like this SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ARADMIN.V_PKGXMLCODE WHERE (CATALOG IS NULL OR (CATALOG <> 0 AND CATALOG <> 2)) AND (NOT (CHILD IS NULL)); and we have a compound index on Catalog and Child.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually struggling with a similar issue. I had a condition where I needed to filter out all the NULL values from my query.

I started with:

```
ColumnName IS NOT NULL
```

This increased my query time manifolds, I tried multiple things after this, like functions where I would just return what I needed, although that was not working as well. Finally a small change did the trick, what I did was:

```
IsNull(ColumnName,'') <> ''
```

And it worked, I am not entirely sure what is the difference, although it worked.

Answer (score 0):

IS NULL does not work with count. You get the error "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'"